# Keeping background image dimensions in SVG shape pattern background

Tags: html, css, svg

**Working on trying to get background images to cover SVG shapes...**

As of right now, I'm trying to use `patterns with width and height set to 100%` and `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`... It works as a background to the `SVG` shape, but it `distorts the background image a bit`. Is there a way to get it to `"cover"` the background `without distorting the background image?`

https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/MQGdmO

```
<pattern id="diamond1" height="100%" width="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/614969/pexels-photo-614969.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />

<g class="diamond-group diamond-group-1">
   <polygon class="diamond-1 diamond" fill="url('#diamond1')" points="260.1,131 131.6,259.6 3,131 131.6,2.4 "/>
   <polygon class="diamond-overlay" points="260.1,131 131.6,259.6 3,131 131.6,2.4 "/>
   <text class="diamond-text pointer" text-anchor="middle" x="130" y="130">ABOUT US</text>
</g>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `image` element, change `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`, or [another setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) that preserves aspect ratio:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzbvZY

I only changed `#diamond3` because that's the image where I could most clearly see the distortion.

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Works great... Thanks!